# find intersection point of two vectors independent from direction

Tags: java, vector, 2d, processing, collision-detection

I have two vectors and i want to know where these vectors will intersect independent from direction or length. So lets just say i would draw an infinite line in either direction and i want to know where those two lines will intersect and get the coordinates. See image below for clarification:

[image]

So i want to know the coordinates of the pink X. But i can only find formulas for calculating the intersection point of two lines with an stard and end point which i dont have :( So i am looking for some help on how to approach this properly.

I have calculated the normalized direction of the blue lines: like so:

```
PVector norm12 = new PVector(-dir12.y, dir12.x);
PVector norm23 = new PVector(dir23.y, -dir23.x);
```

Some context on why i want to do this: 
I am trying to find the center point of a circle created from 3 points.

All this is in 2D

If extra information is needed i am happy to provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've a endless line which is defined by a point `P` and a normalized direction `R` and a second endless line, which is defined by a point `Q` and a direction `S`, then the intersection point of the endless lines `X` is:

[image]

```non
alpha ... angle between Q-P and R
beta  ... angle between R and S

gamma  =  180° - alpha - beta

h  =  | Q - P | * sin(alpha)
u  =  h / sin(beta)

t  = | Q - P | * sin(gamma) / sin(beta)

t  =  dot(Q-P, (S.y, -S.x)) / dot(R, (S.y, -S.x))  =  determinant(mat2(Q-P, S)) / determinant(mat2(R, S))
u  =  dot(Q-P, (R.y, -R.x)) / dot(R, (S.y, -S.x))  =  determinant(mat2(Q-P, R)) / determinant(mat2(R, S))

X  =  P + R * t  =  Q + S * u
```

This can be calculated by the use of [`PVector`](https://processing.org/reference/PVector.html), as follows:

```java
// Intersect 2 endless lines
// line 1: "P" is on endless line, the direction is "dir1" ("R")
// line 2: "Q" is on endless line, the direction is "dir2" ("S")
PVector Intersect( PVector P, PVector dir1, PVector Q, PVector dir2) {

    PVector R = dir1.copy();
    PVector S = dir2.copy();
    R.normalize();
    S.normalize();

    PVector QP  = PVector.sub(Q, P);
    PVector SNV = new PVector(S.y, -S.x);

    float t  =  QP.dot(SNV) / R.dot(SNV); 

    PVector X = PVector.add(P, PVector.mult(R, t));
    return X;
}
```

See the example:

[image]

```java
void setup() {
    size(500,500);
}

void draw() {

    background(0, 0, 0);

    stroke(255);
    fill(255, 0, 0);

    PVector l1p1 = new PVector(250, 150);
    PVector l1p2 = new PVector(300, 300);
    PVector l2p1 = new PVector(200, 180);
    PVector l2p2 = new PVector(300, 220);
    PVector l3p1 = new PVector(200, 300);
    PVector l3p2 = new PVector(250, 280);

    line(l1p1.x, l1p1.y, l1p2.x, l1p2.y);
    line(l2p1.x, l2p1.y, l2p2.x, l2p2.y);
    line(l3p1.x, l3p1.y, l3p2.x, l3p2.y);

    PVector dir1 = PVector.sub(l1p2, l1p1);
    PVector dir2 = PVector.sub(l2p2, l2p1);
    PVector dir3 = PVector.sub(l3p2, l3p1);

    PVector x1 = Intersect(l1p1, dir1, l2p1, dir2);
    circle(x1.x, x1.y, 10);
    PVector x2 = Intersect(l1p1, dir1, l3p1, dir3);
    circle(x2.x, x2.y, 10);
    PVector x3 = Intersect(l2p1, dir2, l3p1, dir3);
    circle(x3.x, x3.y, 10);
}
```

Note, if the lines are parallel then the scalars of the returned point (`PVector` object) are infinit. This can be evaluated by `Float.isInfinite`. e.g:

```java
if (!Float.isInfinite(x1.x) || !Float.isInfinite(x1.y))
    circle(x1.x, x1.y, 10);
```

Comment: am i correct to state that the directions of the vectors doesn't matter for the intersection point of the two vectors?

Comment: @FutureCake Sorry, but I don't know what you mean. Of course the directions are important, because they define the direction of the endless line. A line is defined by a point and a direction. But it is not important where the direction comes form.