# Detecting Number of Intersections of a line with a polygon

Tags: animation, math, image-processing, processing

I already asked this question on the signal processing stack exchange but did not get any answers. You're my only hope StackOverflow. Please help thanks:

As a part of a math essay, I am writing a program that detects intersections of a line that is drawn with a shape that is inputted.

For example, in the shape below, The polygon is the input image of a given size. The ray has been drawn onto the polygon starting from within the polygon. How can I detect the number of times the ray crosses the boundary of the polygon.

Also, the polygon is always a closed polygon.

please see the image here:

[image]

A thought that originally came to my mind was to fill the polygon with the same colour as the border (black). And then count the number of times a ray would meet black followed by white.

My problem with this method is that I don't really know how to trace along a line and check each point and I'm guessing that it would be an extremely expensive process to continuously check along the line.

I'm using Processing 3 right now but I'm okay to use any other software/platform except MatLab because I don't have access to it right now.

Comment: Can you easily "decompose" the polygon into it's lines? Because if you can, then you can apply some simple line collision detection algorithm on them, and you're golden.

Comment: Hi! That’s a great idea. I had had the thought and I remember briefly trying to find some existing library or tool that could do that. I wasn’t able to find anything but I’m still looking. Would you know of anything that can do that (ideally on processing)?

Answer (score 5):

If you've a endless line which is defined by a point `P` and a normalized direction `R` and a second endless line, which is defined by a point `Q` and a direction `S`, then the intersection point of the endless lines `X` is:

[image]

```non
alpha ... angle between Q-P and R
beta  ... angle between R and S

gamma  =  180° - alpha - beta

h  =  | Q - P | * sin(alpha)
u  =  h / sin(beta)

t  = | Q - P | * sin(gamma) / sin(beta)

t  =  dot(Q-P, (S.y, -S.x)) / dot(R, (S.y, -S.x))  =  determinant(mat2(Q-P, S)) / determinant(mat2(R, S))
u  =  dot(Q-P, (R.y, -R.x)) / dot(R, (S.y, -S.x))  =  determinant(mat2(Q-P, R)) / determinant(mat2(R, S))

X  =  P + R * t  =  Q + S * u
```

<sub>See also [find intersection point of two vectors independent from direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58541430/find-intersection-point-of-two-vectors-independent-from-direction)</sub>

If you have a ine from `l1p1` to `l1p2` and a second line from `l2p1` to `l2p2` then:

```
P = l1p1
Q = l2p1;
R = normalize(l1p2 - l1p1)
S = normalize(l2p2 - l2p1)
```

`normalize` computes the [Unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) of a vector. The length of a unit vector is 1.

Since the lines are not endless, you have to evaluate if the intersection point is on the line segment. Compute the length of the lines, and the distances from the start of the liens to the intersection point. Verify if the distances (computed by the [Dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)) are greater >= 0 and <= the length of the line.
In the following

```
len1 = | l1p2 - l1p1 |
len2 = | l2p2 - l2p1 |

distOnL1 = dot(X - P, R);
distOnL2 = dot(X - Q, S);

intersecting = distOnL1 >= 0 AND distOnL1 <= len1 AND distOnL2 >= 0 AND distOnL2 <= len2
```

This can be calculated by the use of [`PVector`](https://processing.org/reference/PVector.html), as follows:

```java
class TIntersection {
   boolean valid = false;
   PVector point = new PVector(0.0, 0.0);
}

// Intersect 2 endless  lines
// line 1: line segment from `l1p1` to `l1p2`
// line 2: line segment from `l2p1` to `l2p2`
TIntersection Intersect(PVector l1p1, PVector l1p2, PVector l2p1, PVector l2p2) {

    PVector P = l1p1;
    PVector Q = l2p1;
    PVector R = PVector.sub(l1p2, l1p1);
    PVector S = PVector.sub(l2p2, l2p1);
    float   len1 = R.mag();
    float   len2 = S.mag();
    R.normalize();
    S.normalize();

    PVector QP  = PVector.sub(Q, P);
    PVector SNV = new PVector(S.y, -S.x);  
    TIntersection isect = new TIntersection();
    float t =  QP.dot(SNV) / R.dot(SNV); 
    isect.point = PVector.add(P, PVector.mult(R, t));

    if (!Float.isInfinite(isect.point.x) || !Float.isInfinite(isect.point.y)) {
        float distOnL1 = PVector.sub(isect.point, P).dot(R);
        float distOnL2 = PVector.sub(isect.point, Q).dot(S);
        isect.valid = distOnL1 >= 0.0 && distOnL1 <= len1 && distOnL2 >= 0.0 && distOnL2 <= len2; 
    } else {
        isect.valid = false; 
    }
    return isect;
}
```

The return value of the function is of type `TIntersection`. The attribute `valid` is `true` if there is an intersection and the lines are not parallel. 
The attribute `point` of type `PVector` is the intersection point, if there is one.

---

See the example:

[image]

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/processing.js/1.6.6/processing.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="pjs"></canvas>
<script type="application/processing" data-processing-target="pjs">
class TIntersection {
    boolean valid = false;
    PVector point = new PVector(0.0, 0.0);
}
 
// Intersect 2 endless  lines
// line 1: line segment from `l1p1` to `l1p2`
// line 2: line segment from `l2p1` to `l2p2`
TIntersection Intersect(PVector l1p1, PVector l1p2, PVector l2p1, PVector l2p2) {
   
    PVector P = l1p1;
    PVector Q = l2p1;
    PVector R = PVector.sub(l1p2, l1p1);
    PVector S = PVector.sub(l2p2, l2p1);
    float   len1 = R.mag();
    float   len2 = S.mag();
    R.normalize();
    S.normalize();
     
    PVector QP  = PVector.sub(Q, P);
    PVector SNV = new PVector(S.y, -S.x);
     
    TIntersection isect = new TIntersection();
    float t =  QP.dot(SNV) / R.dot(SNV); 
    isect.point = PVector.add(P, PVector.mult(R, t));
     
    //if (!Float.isInfinite(isect.point.x) || !Float.isInfinite(isect.point.y)) {
        float distOnL1 = PVector.sub(isect.point, P).dot(R);
        float distOnL2 = PVector.sub(isect.point, Q).dot(S);
        isect.valid = distOnL1 >= 0.0 && distOnL1 <= len1 && distOnL2 >= 0.0 && distOnL2 <= len2; 
    //} else {
    //    isect.valid = false; 
    //}
    return isect;
}
 
ArrayList<PVector> poly;
PVector[] line_p, move;
 
void setup() {
    size(500,500);
    
    poly = new ArrayList();
    poly.add(new PVector(175, 100));
    poly.add(new PVector(175, 300));
    poly.add(new PVector(200, 300));
    poly.add(new PVector(225, 400));
    poly.add(new PVector(275, 350));
    poly.add(new PVector(275, 200));
    poly.add(new PVector(325, 200));
    poly.add(new PVector(325, 100));
    
    line_p = new PVector[2];
    line_p[0] = new PVector(150, 400);
    line_p[1] = new PVector(380, 100);
    
    move = new PVector[2];
    move[0] = new PVector(random(2)-1, random(2)-1);
    move[1] = new PVector(random(2)-1, random(2)-1);
}

void draw() {
  
    // randomize points
    for (int i=0; i < line_p.length; ++i ) {
        line_p[i] = PVector.add(line_p[i], move[i]);
        if (line_p[i].x < 50 || line_p[i].x > width-50)
            move[i].x *= -1; 
        if (line_p[i].y < 50 || line_p[i].y > height-50)
            move[i].y *= -1;    
        move[i].x = max(-1, min(1, move[i].x+random(0.2)-0.1));
        move[i].y = max(-1, min(1, move[i].y+random(0.2)-0.1));
    }
  
    // clear background
    background(0, 0, 0);
    
    stroke(255);
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    
    // draw line
    line(line_p[0].x, line_p[0].y, line_p[1].x, line_p[1].y);
    
    // draw polygon and intersections
    int intersections = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < poly.size(); i++) {
        PVector poly_p1 = poly.get(i);
        PVector poly_p2 = poly.get((i+1) %  poly.size());
        
        line(poly_p1.x, poly_p1.y, poly_p2.x, poly_p2.y);
        
        TIntersection x = Intersect(line_p[0], line_p[1], poly_p1, poly_p2);
        if (x.valid) {
            ellipse(x.point.x, x.point.y, 10, 10);
            intersections ++;
        }
    }
    
    // draw intersection count
    fill(255);
    textSize(24);
    text("intersections: " + str(intersections), 20, 40); 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Under certain assumptions you can do this without using a lot of math to obtain approximate intersection points.

The assumptions are:

- your input polygon image is drawn with non-antialising lines
- you can draw a non-antialising line (or a ray)
- thickness of the lines is 1 pixel

Take your polygon image, let's call it `poly`. Threshold this image such that the background pixels are 0 and polygon pixels are non-zero, say 1.

Create an empty image (all pixels values 0) having the same size as the `poly`, let's call it `ray`. Draw your non-antialising ray on this image with non-zero pixels values, say 1.

Take the sum or these two images, `result = poly + ray`. Now the intersections should have pixel value 2 in the `result` image, and you can easily extract their coordinates.

Here, all images are assumed to have a single channel.